# How do you exclude generated files like "exploded-aar" from Android Studio "Find in Path"?

Tags: android, android-studio

I often use the “Find in Path” action (shift + command + f) to find things inside of my project in Android Studio. The search results often include generated files. One common path is “app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/…”. This really “pollutes” my results.

[image: Screenshot of results including generated files]

Is there any way to to prevent Android Studio from including generated files in search results? I know I can adjust my search scope so it isn’t “Whole Project” and instead I could use a custom search scope, but is that really necessary? I don’t remember having to do this in the past and it seems like a more recent issue. Also, when I change my scope, it doesn’t seem to stick. It often resets and it’s a pain to keep setting it back.

Does this happen to anyone else?

Has it always been this way and I am just remembering incorrectly?

If I do have to use a custom scope, can someone recommend what that custom scope should be?

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: Find settings]